# Replacing conditional chaining with an older method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code that is using conditional chaining such as

```
productQuantity = purchases.filter((pObj) => pObj.elements[0]?.prodType?.id === purchase.elements[0]?.prodType?.id && pObj.sold === purchase.sold).length
```

It works fine but I need to convert the chained conditionals to an older method and I'm not sure how. Can anyone advise ?

Reason being that PM2 does not support chaining conditional operators.

Comment: You would just have to manually check for null/undefined values before dereferencing them.  For example, check if `pObj.elements[0]` is neither `null` or `undefined` before calling `pObj.elements[0].prodType`, and so on repeated for each optional-chained operation.

Comment: super-long version of what @David explained: https://jsfiddle.net/v1zby2ag/ this is just for illustrative purposes, of course IT goldman's answer below should be used in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this. Replacing all `key?.key2` with `key && key.key2`

```js
productQuantity = purchases.filter((pObj) => {
    return pObj.elements[0] && pObj.elements[0].prodType && purchase.elements[0] && purchase.elements[0].prodType && pObj.elements[0].prodType.id === purchase.elements[0].prodType.id && pObj.sold === purchase.sold
}).length
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this.

First, we make the observation that the we are selecting an `id` from two similar objects: we can therefore refactor the logic required to select the `id` into a common function:

```
function selectId(item) {
    if (item) {
        const elements = item.elements;
        if (elements) {
            const element = elements[0];
            if (element) {
                const prodType = element.prodType;
                if (prodType) {
                    const id = prodType.id;
                    return id;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also flatten the selection (which may or may not be more readable/maintainable):

```
function selectId(item) {
  if (!item) return undefined;

  const elements = item.elements;
  if (!elements) return undefined;

  const element = elements[0];
  if (!element) return undefined;

  const prodType = element.prodType;
  if (!element) return undefined;

  const id = prodType.id;
  return id;
}
```

Once you have that, then your filter comes down to this:

```
productQuantity = purchases.filter( isMatch ).length;

function isMatch(obj) {
    let itemId = selectId(obj);
    let purchaseId = selectId(purchase);
    const shouldKeep = itemId == purchaseId
                  && obj.sold === purchase.sold;
    return shouldKeep
}
```